# How to check if a field in Firestore document is a Map?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this document:

[image]

As you can see, the field `map` is of type Map. I read the data from Firestore using this function:

```
async function getJohn() {
  var ref = doc(db, "users/john");
  const document = await getDoc(ref);
  if(document.exists()) {
    let map = document.data().map
    if (map instanceof Map) {
      alert("Is a Map.")
    } else {
      alert("It's not a Map.")
    }
  }
}
```

Even if the `map` is a Map in the document, I always get:

> It's not a Map.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the database side they call it a `map`, but once it arrives client side it is just a plain javascript object, never a javascript `Map`. If you want to distinguish it from other objects, maybe you could do a check like this:

```
if (typeof map === 'object' && map !== null && !Array.isArray(map)) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore maps is an object so I think this will fit your needs:

```
let map = document.data().map
if (
  typeof map === 'object' &&
  // as typeof array === 'object' we need to check if is not an array
  !Array.isArray( map )
) {
  alert("Is a Map.")
} else {
  alert("It's not a Map.")
}
```